# Cross-Site Scripting Phishing Through Frames

Tags: php

how we can protect Cross-Site Scripting Phishing Through Frames.

Answer (score 1):

Have your users come to you directly, NOT through an intermediary.  Use a valid SSL certificate so they can know they are truly at your web site.  Have a recognizable name.

Require a valid, unpredictable key to allow making changes via your site.  In other words, use a session in conjunction with an *unpredictable* nonce before users can make changes.

To protect yourself from being used to attack other sites, do not allow your users to post HTML content that will be displayed, without escaping, to other users.

Comment: can u send me some reference or code To protect myself from being used to attack other sites, and how to protect the users to post HTML content that will be displayed, without escaping, to other users

Comment: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/preventing-csrf-and-xsrf-attacks.html

Understanding is important.  There is no one-size-fits-all solution.

I'll say that again.  *You must take the time to understand what you are doing*.  Otherwise, nothing and nobody can help you.